# Remote debugging javascript on IntelliJ with JetBrains Chrome extension isn't working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, intellij-idea, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to set up a debugger for some JS files which I am editing on IntelliJ (2020.1.4). I followed the instructions here [Debug with JetBrains Chrome extension﻿](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-jetbrains-chrome-extension.html), and I think I've completed all the steps as illustrated:

[image]

Right settings on Chrome Extension as with default IntelliJ port, and extension itself says it is connected to IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.4

[image]

I have below breakpoint in my javascript file and I ran the application on debug [image]mode.

[image]

But on my chrome console, I saw it going past my breakpoint as it print above log statement and on IDE I didn't observe any stops. Is there like a missing step I didn't do?

Comment: is it TypeScript or Javascript project? what run configuration do you use? Please record a screencast that shows your steps. Note that Chrome extension is not currently required for debugging/Live Edit. It doesn't work reliably in most recent Chrome versions (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-37230), and we recommend turning it off in **Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger | Live Edit, Use JetBrains IDE Support extension for debugging and Live Edit**

Comment: vuejs it think theres libraries with typescript. like vuex

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I need to click on "Inspect on IDEA"